# Running a query with PHP/MySQL then reordering the results by another column

Tags: php, sql, mysql, sql-order-by

This SQL query gives me the results I want; however, I want the results ordered by a different column:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM post 
    INNER JOIN account ON post.account_id = account.account_id 
WHERE post_id > new 
ORDER BY post_date 
ASC LIMIT 10;
```

I can not simply change `ORDER BY post_date ASC` to `ORDER BY post_id DESC`, while that will in fact order the query the way I want it... it will give me the wrong 10 posts.

I simply want to take the **EXACT RESULTS** of the above query then reorder the results by the `post_id`. 

I would like to do this with SQL if possible, if not I could order the results by adding the results into a new array reversed.

Comment: Your query should fail, returning MySQL error 1060: Duplicate column name because of the `account_id` existing in both tables.

Comment: It did, I made a few changes to the database and it all works like a charm now, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a subquery to reorder:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM post
  INNER JOIN account ON post.account_id = account.account_id
  WHERE post_id > neww
  ORDER BY post_date ASC LIMIT 10;
) ORDER BY post_id
```

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm, I cant believe I have been searching 2 days for this :(...

Comment: Thanks, I thought that this would be the way to go with my own problem (On SQL Server 2k8). You've confirmed it for me. +1

Comment: This query is missing AS, should be ... ) AS x ORDER BY post_id. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/from-clause-subqueries.html

Answer (score 4):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM post
    INNER JOIN account
    ON post.account_id = account.account_id
    WHERE post_id > neww
    ORDER BY post_date ASC
    LIMIT 10) AS T1
ORDER BY post_id DESC
```

Comment: Wow, Notice the race condition that occurred here. (both posted Mar 1 at 22:13) While both answers are correct only one can get the "correct" answer. I find it interesting that Mark's answer names the sub-query `T1` and then doesn't reference it.